# how to calculate threshold value in eigenfaces or pca algorithm for each images in training set in matlab during face recognition?

Tags: matlab, face-recognition, threshold, eigenvector

I wrote matlab code for face recognition using eigen faces.I got the normalized image,mean image, eigen faces, and I calculated min and max eucledian distance.Now I have to compare eucledian distance with the threshold to recognize a face. How is the threshold value calculated for each face image? what will is the next step?

```
  %show the reconstructed image.
  subplot(1,2,2)
  imagesc(ReshapedImage); colormap('gray');
  title('Reconstructed image','fontsize',18)

  InImWeight = [];
  for i=1:size(u,2)
   t = u(:,i)';
  WeightOfInputImage = dot(t,Difference');
  InImWeight = [InImWeight; WeightOfInputImage];
  end

  ll = 1:M;
  figure(68)
  subplot(1,2,1)
  stem(ll,InImWeight)
   title('Weight of Input Face','fontsize',14)

    % Find Euclidean distance
     e=[];
   for i=1:size(omega,2)
       q = omega(:,i);
     DiffWeight = InImWeight-q;
       mag = norm(DiffWeight);
       e = [e mag];
         end

     kk = 1:size(e,2);
     subplot(1,2,2)
     stem(kk,e)
     title('Eucledian distance of input image','fontsize',14)

      MaximumValue=max(e)
      MinimumValue=min(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not a standard rule for the threshold selection in face recognition.

Since you seem to have a training set of images, you can try to select a threshold based on a biometric performance metric, e.g. the false acceptance rate (FAR) and false match rate (FMR).

You can try to classify the images in your training set by varying the threshold value within a certain range and accept the detection of images that have a `MinimumValue` below the threshold. 
Based on the results you get you can selected an appropriate threshold for your training set.

Comment: The range of distance (min and max) is it standard because changing the method i find other range of distance and how to find it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm stuck almost the same. Although missing the story, and it's like spamming my doubt.

I'll point:
Actually the threshold is not calculated. It is estimated and is chosen empirically. It is something to try and test.
You must set a value and compare acepts and rejections, and above all: to assess how many false acept (FA) and false rejection (FR)

Ideally it is expected that the threshold EER is such that, when the rate of FA equals FR rate is achieved.

What you can do is take the range [Min, Max] distances and test 10, 20, or the amount that you want thresholds within range.
Some papers suggest that the threshold is a percentage value relative to the maximum. That is something like 0.8 * Max.

Surely you should try more than once to find the threshold that works best for each person.

The best find ready. You've got your threshold for each image.
I hope I've been helpful.

Comment: The range [Min, Max]  of distance do we find it by comparing images of the train set ?